# Can I deboard and take rest at intermediate station and continue the journey till destination after 1 or 2 days gap?

Tags: trains, indian-railways, train-stations, south-india

Single reservation ticket taken for travel from Bangalore to Kadapa with intermediate station: Tirupati.

Can I deboard at intermediate station Tirupati and after 1 or 2 days continue my journey?

Can I board any train which travels to Kadapa from Tirupati with same single reserved ticket booked from Bangalore to Kadapa?

Please note the distance from source to destination station is less than 500kms.

Answer (score 11):

The answer is **no**. A reserved train ticket in India is usually issued for a specific train for a specific day/time, and therefore on any later train / day it won't be valid and you won't have a reservation.

You might have been able to use the ["break journey" rules](http://www.indianrail.gov.in/break_Journey.html) defined by Indian Rail if you were travelling on a longer train journey - just not in the this case when you say the journey is shorter than 500 km.

Answer (score 4):

In some senses the answer can be YES.

Just for future visitors you cannot have a break journey, but since there are no direct trains from Bangalore to Cuddappah you can technically get away with a break if you book your ticket in a counter (not in IRCTC as far as I know at the time of writing, but my IRCTC knowledge is a bit outdated).

So basically you have to plan your trip in such a manner that your train to Tirupati and your second train from Tirupathi are not more than 24 hours apart. This way you can book a "through journey ticket" which will allow you to combine the second ticket for the purposes of fare calculations and then book your second ticket in a train that starts from Tirupathy within 24 hours note the rule says.

["it should not be treated as break journey provided such halt is for less than 24 hours"](http://www.indianrailways.gov.in/railwayboard/view_section.jsp?id=0,2,281,878)